# Can not run unit test from PyCharm in Django project

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm

Whenever I try to test some existing (and working) unit tests in my Django project with PyCharm pro, I get the following error:

```
File "/home/user/pycharm-2018.2/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py", 
line 156, in run_tests return super(DjangoTeamcityTestRunner, self).run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
TypeError: run_tests() takes exactly 2 arguments (12 given)
```

The way unit tests are executed seems to be hardcoded in PyCharm helpers. 
The project is based on Django 1.9. Could that explain the incompatibility of the test runner? Or did I miss something in setup?

Comment: run **`python manage.py test`** command to run test